# Different login credentials show different tables mysql

Tags: mysql, database

When i just write "mysql" in bash - it show only 2 databases.
When i write mysql -u root -p and then enter password - 2 more db occur.
Why is it happening?
+ bonus question: i backed up "data" directory from previous mysql installation, which crashed.
How to restore tables from .ibd and .frm files?
mac os 10.9

Comment: Bonus answer: you set up a new mysql server, stop it, replace the data directory and my.cnf with the ones from your backup, then start up the new server, inspect the data, and use mysqldump to export what you need.  Any other approach falls into the category of "if you don't already know, then it's too hard to explain."

Comment: ok. and if i didn't make a copy of my.cnf?
is that still possible?

Comment: Yes, but the new server may require a few changes to its my.cnf before it will start... any important discrepancy should leave a message in the hostname.err mysql error log that will give you an idea of what's not right. The new server's my.cnf doesn't have to be identical, it just can't be explicitly incompatible in a few ways.

Answer (score 3):

1. > Why is it happening?

   As documented under [`SHOW DATABASES` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-databases.html):

   > You see only those databases for which you have some kind of privilege, unless you have the global [`SHOW DATABASES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-databases.html) privilege.

   Presumably the account under which you connect to MySQL when no explicit credentials are provided (i.e. as set in the relevant option file) only has permission to see two of your databases.
2. > How to restore tables from .ibd and .frm files?

   See [Copying Tablespaces to Another Server (Transportable Tablespaces)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/tablespace-copying.html).  If the files are in the server's data directory, you can use `IMPORT TABLESPACE`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tablename IMPORT TABLESPACE
   ```

Comment: what about bonus question?